# using IF statement in mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to find a way to insert a value into one of two columns depending on which one is NULL.

```
$accept_sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE user_properties 
    IF(followup_offer <> NULL, fstatus=?)
    ELSE (istatus=?) 
    WHERE id=?");

$accept_sth->execute($_POST['option'], $_POST['id']);
```

I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Put your conditional logic in the php, not in the sql statement.  Modify your SQL statement based on the condition of `followup_offer` in the php.

Comment: but then I would have to query the database to find out if followup_offer is NULL right. I was wanting to do it in one query.

Comment: Get `followup_offer` in one of your existing / previous queries.  You have status and id, so get `followup_offer` at that same time.

Comment: well, ok I could do that. is it not possible to do the if?

Comment: yes, but you have to select the `followup_offer` before the if

Comment: It may be possible, but it will require some unnecessary brain damage to get it right, and it's going to make for a messy sql statement.  Simple is better, if possible.

Comment: @cale_b LOL. Fair enough. In fact I am almost done writing your way, so thanks!

Comment: @cale_b `it will require some unnecessary brain damage to get it righ`...it's so true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *...brain damage...* necessary. You can do it with a query

```sql
UPDATE user_properties 
   SET fstatus = IF(followup_offer IS NULL, fstatus, ?),
       istatus = IF(followup_offer IS NULL, ?, istatus)
 WHERE id = ?
```

**Note:** the only possible drawback for some scenarios of this type of query with conditional `SET` is that both columns are updated every time (one with a value and one with the old one).

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29950/1)** demo

Comment: Although I went with another solution that works (omitting the IF all together) this is the answer to the question I had. I don't see a big issue with both columns being updated. Thank you!

Comment: Brain damage, good grief. The comment suggesting splitting data-logic between PHP and MySQL is a terrible recommendation. This is an excellent answer.